# ALLOW only some strings in a url pattern via .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I need to block access to random url strings to foil bots, and allow only certain strings, some of which must contain partially random content, using htaccess and regex.

I need to allow access to:/shows/page/, /shows/sort/, /shows/genre/, /shows/release/, **/shows/!(any string)** - And deny: /shows/"anything else"/.
The need to ALLOW access to any url that contains **/shows/!(any string)/** makes listing specific allowed urls impossible.

Currently I am using

```
RewriteRule ^shows/[^srgp!] - [NC,F]
```

which is partially working by allowing access to the above urls and denying access to any address that begins with anything except "/shows/s,r,g,p,!"

However, it only compares based on the first character so allows /shows/**s**omething, /shows/**r**andom, /shows/**g**enerate, and similar...so a lot of unwanted traffic is still getting through.

I need to allow the entire word to be compared and also allow "!" followed by any string.  I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^shows/^((?!page|sort|genre|release|!).)*$ - [NC,F]
```

and various similar solutions, but have not been able to hit on a successful implementation.

Comment: You are likely to receive better help at webmasters stackexchange: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: And what does "but have not been able to hit on a successful implementation" actually mean?

Comment: Means nothing I have tried works completely right, according to the goal stated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured out a way, just not as clean as I wanted - I added an extra "!" character to the /shows/!(random_string) url so it is /shows/!!(random_string).  I then added a separate match rule for the second character of every allowed url:

```
#block url pattern SHOWS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shows/[^srgp!] - [NC,F]
RewriteRule ^shows/p[^a!] - [NC,F]
RewriteRule ^shows/s[^o!] - [NC,F]
RewriteRule ^shows/g[^e!] - [NC,F]
RewriteRule ^shows/r[^e!] - [NC,F]
RewriteRule ^shows/![^!] - [NC,F]
</IfModule>
#end block url pattern
```

This then matches the first two characters of my allowed urls, instead of just the first one, and blocks anything else, which seems to have added an acceptable level of security.  If I have to I can add the entire url strings in a similar way, which will also make it necessary to add another "!" character to the allowed url /shows/!!(random_string) for each new character allowed - this I am doing by way of permalink structure.